# Exporting Cookies with Postman Collection

Tags: cookies, collections, postman, postman-collection

I was trying to export my Postman Collection but it is not exporting Cookies with that. Is there any method that I can use to export cookies along with my requests as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the cookies as environment variables as well as reading/ setting them from environment variables.
You then would also need to export the environment.

`pm.environment.set('my_cookie', pm.cookies.get('cookie'));`